# Why do odd aspect ratios look stretched in browser on Mac using actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash

I have a simple AS3 swf that captures the user's webcam feed and displays it. I am trying to set the video to 16:9 aspect ratio. According to Adobe, if I use setMode() on the Camera object, I can set it to any aspect ratio and if the camera can't handle it, Flash will crop the video to fit the area. This works great on Windows. I tried with half a dozen different webcams and all cropped properly. On my Mac (OSX 10.8.3) and on a co-worker's mac, however, the image does not get cropped and is instead stretched to fit when the swf is displayed in a browser (tried with chrome, Firefox and safari). However, if I publish the swf in the Flash IDE (CS 5.5), it looks correct. When tracing out the cam.width and cam.height, I noticed that cam.height is 90 in the IDE, but 120 in the browser. This leads me to think it's an issue with Flash Player on mac, but I can't seem to find any mention of this issue in the forums. Anyone have any workarounds, or word on whether or not this is a known bug?

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var video:Video = new Video(320,180);
cam.setMode(320, 180, 15, true);
video.attachCamera(cam);
video.x = 100;
video.y = 20;
addChild(video);
```

Comment: Sorry it seems to depend on the driver itself: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1027811

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a OS problem that randomly sizes the SWF.  Instead of tracing the width and height, make a text box showing the width and height values as a string and run it in your browser and see if it shows 120 or 90 then you can use some HTML code to re-size the SWF.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a bug in Flash player. A couple days ago this problem magically fixed itself on my mac but a co-worker still had the problem. I'm running Flash player 11.7.700.203 and she had 11.7.700.202 and when she upgraded it fixed the issue.

edit: Spoke too soon - this upgrade only seems to work in Google Chrome. Safari continues to see the problem, even after upgrading to 11.7.700.203.